# Download a single .txt using QFtp

Tags: c++, file, qt, ftp

I've got a problem with QFtp. I wanna download a single .txt file with a single line(8 bytes) from my server, so I've written the following code, but it doesn't work.
The file "actions.txt" were created in the folder1 directory. I can see the size of it pretty well in the client-side. But the file is not being written. I'm getting an empty file.

```
QFile* actionFile = new QFile("action.txt");
QFtp *ftp = new QFtp(parent);

void Dialog::getActionFile() 
{ 
    actionFile->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    ftp->connectToHost("mydomain.de"); 
    ftp->login("user", "pw"); 
    ftp->cd("folder1"); 
    ftp->get("action.txt",actionFile); 
    ftp->close(); 
    actionFile->close(); 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to specify the transfer type as `Ascii` in the call to `QFtp::get`? (I'm assuming `action.txt` is an ASCII text file.) Also, you might want to look at the documentation for `QFtp::get`; the documentation I found for it indicates that it starts an asynchronous operation, and may return before it's complete. You may need to wait for it to complete before closing the connection and the output file.

Comment: Already tried the Ascii transfer type, still doesnt work. And I tried not closing the file at all. And also closing after a amount of time. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of *several methods* of [`QFtp`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qftp.html#get) says:

> The function **does not block and returns immediately**. The command is
>   scheduled, and its execution is performed asynchronously. The function
>   returns a unique identifier which is passed by `commandStarted()` and
>   `commandFinished()`.

So you need to wait for the appropriate signals to be emitted.

Note that you can also use [`QNetworkRequest`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qnetworkrequest.html) to request the whole ftp URL (I think even with username and password inside the URL) to download the file.

Comment: As i said above, I alredy tried removing the file.close() and did not work.

Comment: @PatrickBassut This is absolutely not what I am talking about... I am talking about listening for signals instead of just writing FTP commands one after the other. They **all** are non-blocking, that means, they are executed asynchronously, so for the file to be written you need to wait for the signal `commandFinished()` which passes the ID you got from `QFtp::get()`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
I treated one step each time the commandFininshed signal was emitted.
like this:

```
void MainWindow::ftpCommandFinished(int id, bool error)
{
    static bool flag = false;
    if(ftp->currentCommand() == QFtp::ConnectToHost)
        checkUpdate();
    if(ftp->currentCommand() == QFtp::Get)
    {
        file->close();
        if(error)
        {
            QMessageBox::warning(this, "Erro!", ftp->errorString());
            deleteLater();
            return;
        }
        if(!flag)
            checkVersion();
        else{
            delete ftp, file;
            ftp = 0; file = 0;
        }
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

the reason of the flag variable is something else that needs further explanations about the program, so i won't go down that road.

Thanks for you help. It somehow helped me a lot.